# How to hide specific fields and the according label in a view, based on field permissions?

Tags: 7, views, entities, users

I have a view called *Profile* that displays some of the user fields. Amongst these is a *Name* field (field_name). I'd like to hide this field except for the administrator and the user himself/herself. I installed the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module, wich nicely gives me the opportunity to mark the field as private. When this is checked, the *Name*'s value disappears in my *Profile* view, but the according label is still there - and that's not very nice.

How can I hide the label aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Name field's edit config popup, remove the text from the Label field and disable the label checkbox; expand the Rewriting section, and paste in the label followed by the name field's  substitution pattern.... it will look something like this `Name: [field_name]`.  Finally,  ensure the option to disable rewriting when field is empty checkbox is checked.