# How to access the user's email field with Field Permissions?

Tags: 7, views, entities, users, emails

This is a sort of sequel to my previous question [How to hide specific fields and the according label in a view, based on field permissions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95533/how-to-hide-specific-fields-and-the-according-label-in-a-view-based-on-field-pe). One of the fields I'm displaying in my view is the standard *User: Email* field. I'd like to hide this field in my view except for the administrator and the user himself/herself.

How can I do that? I can't find a way to access the field with the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. If someone could show me a way to do that (my previous question is solved), this question would be solved.

Or is the Field Permissions module not suitable for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem! I installed the [Email Field](https://drupal.org/project/email) module and added a 'Emailadress' field to the user fields. I marked it as private with the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. Then, I created a rule that rewrites the 'Emailadress' field with the standard email after a user account has been created or updated. Finally, I added the 'Emailadress' field to my view.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is a duplicate of this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727513/drupal-show-hide-fields-in-view

The two solutions are:

- in the field template, display the content depending on the user role
  or
- create two views displays, one for each of your user role

Comment: Mind that my problem hasn't only to do with user roles, but also with uid's, since the profile's "owner" should be able to see his/her e-mail field.

Comment: then the first solution (template) would be acceptable with something like: global $user; if($user->uid == $row->my_uid || in_array('my_role', $user->roles)) { print $my_field; }

Answer (score 0):

I think Matt's answer is very close.

I would go the route of creating *three* views displays.  The first display filters the content for *Current User* only and displays the email.   The second view shows the email, and the display visibility permissions is set to *administrators* only.  The third view hides the email field, but makes the view visible to anyone.

The fact is that Field Permissions has no effect on the email field, because it is unfortunately one of those "special case" field in Drupal (that existed long before the Field API did).

Comment: Thanks for your respons. I think your idea should work, but it looks quite a lot of work to me for such a little feature. I found a, in my opinion slightly easier, solution. You can read it underneath.